# Post the data to the java web services in python

Tags: python, web-services

I am puzzling with the webservice function *addNews()* in python. 
some codes such as:

```
import requests
from suds.client import Client
import json

test = Client("http://localhost:8080/NewsService?WSDL",autoblend=True)
print(test)  # success
mydata=("data1","data2","data3",170805,1046,1)  
aa=test.service.addNews(mydata,"1578977978","dxh","","") 
print(aa) # Can't get the correct response.
```

but it always is not successed.
some WSDL as the following:

```
<wsdl:operation name="addNews">
<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input name="addNewsRequest">
<wsdlsoap:body namespace="http://webservice.vsb.webber" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</wsdl:input>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="addNews" parameterOrder="jsonString ownerString account pageJsonString attachfiles attachfilesfilenames">
<wsdl:input name="addNewsRequest" message="impl:addNewsRequest"/>
<wsdl:output name="addNewsResponse" message="impl:addNewsResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:message name="addNewsRequest">
<wsdl:part type="soapenc:string" name="jsonString"/>
<wsdl:part type="soapenc:string" name="ownerString"/>
<wsdl:part type="soapenc:string" name="account"/>
<wsdl:part type="impl:ArrayOf_soapenc_string" name="pageJsonString"/>
<wsdl:part type="impl:ArrayOf_apachesoap_DataHandler" name="attachfiles"/>
<wsdl:part type="impl:ArrayOf_soapenc_string" name="attachfilesfilenames"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's java? There's no semicolons.

Comment: That would be python, why does this have the Java tag?

Comment: use the python to access java webservices